# Trying to troubleshoot a OP's question

Tags: discussion, support

Alright, Am trying to help troubleshoot this [OP's question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38176/web-page-not-available-please-help), and the fact that the OP has a very low rep, and thus a new-comer on the scene.

Is there anyway of getting that OP to join the chat site to minimize comments that end up long and winded due to the OP being vague about and not knowing how/what to do to help us troubleshoot?

Basically, TL;DR; With a rep score < 20 (or minimum requirement of rep count to enter chat site) to move the comments into chat...How to do it? Or deal with it?

Comment: Funnily enough the userid is 'killed slowly', troubleshooting like this is *killing me slowly*... xD <offtopic/>

Comment: 19 comments and counting so far... This sort of thing would more than likely result in question being closed for "too chatty"?

Comment: Have called it quits with the OP in question... I tried.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think there's simply not an ideal solution for situations like this at the moment. You can, however, upvote/favorite/bounty [Invite low rep users to participate in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100291/invite-low-rep-users-to-participate-in-chat) over on MSO if you'd like (proposes allowing higher rep users to invite lower ones into chat).

I'd say the best course of action currently is to just hash out as much as you can in the comments, then try to get that information edited into the question. If you reach that point then you can always flag comments for deletion as "obsolete", or flag one of the comments with a custom note along the lines of "every comment after this one is now obsolete etc etc". That way the comments can get cleaned up and the information will be retained.

And, of course, you can encourage the OP to try their hand at answering some questions since you only need 2 answer upvotes to get chat privileges.

Comment: Thanks for that treasure! Have edited the question and marked the 2nd comment from the OP onwards for deletion.

Comment: Cheers for that clean-up on the question :)